# Flutter: How to save widget state in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, state, state-management

I have an app which has a `ListView.builder()` which builds widgets. Those widgets fetch an image from firebase cloud storage. Every time those widgets go off the screen and come back, the widget fetches the image from firebase cloud storage again. I want to make it so that it doesn't fetch the image again but rather displays the image it already got when it is rebuilt if the widget already got the image.

It currently looks like this: https://cln.sh/S9Ky0L.

Comment: Fetching constantly from Firebase Storage is a really bad practice. You should be saving the final URL over Firestore and consuming only once.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's bad practice and I don't want that behavior. What I'm asking is how do I make it so that it doesn't do that? `ListView.builder()` doesn't keep all widgets loaded but only visible ones. So it rebuilds a widget when ever it goes off screen then back on screen again. How can i make it so that it doesn't fetch the image again once it is rebuilt. I currently fetch the image using the firebase cloud storage package and the `.get()` method on the reference to the image.

Comment: The only possible solution is using the Cache Image Network library but ONLY if you have the end url on Firestore. Firebase Storage needs to fetch every single time. You could do that if you downloaded once, "save" it on a list, then check if exists in that list and fetch the end URL + Cache Image Network. This doesn't scale well as it will because a larger and larger memory logic usage

Comment: One option is to fetch every single possible image before hand into a List in RAM (memory) and then show it on your list. This process will take a longer time but you'll fetch it once. And the other is the one you're doing. For the very own nature of ListView, they can't keep an element in memory because you'll have BIGGER issue (getting an out of memory exception)

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Is there a way to automatically cache an image with the firebase cloud storage package instead of fetching it every time? Also, is there a way to only keep a certain number of widgets loaded at once to avoid an out of memory exception as I definitely don't want that?

Comment: No, that's why I'm saying firebase storage doesn't work that way. Either you use Firestore to save the URLs or you need to fetch it at least once every time you open the app and get each link inside a List<String> to show it on the ListView. And no, you can preload items in memory using a ListView as it break the entire logic of a ListView. ScrollView does work, but it will create the out of memory issue it loads everything.

Comment: Use keepAlive widget

Comment: @Rahul What's the difference between using `keepAlive` in a `ListView.builder()` vs just using a `ListView()`?

Comment: Default is keepalive=true for listview or listview.builder. so it wound't make sense to add another keepalive.

Comment: @Rahul doesn't `ListView.builder()` only keep the widgets currently visible on the screen alive and disposes of others not visible while `ListView()` keeps all widgets alive?

Comment: typically yes. but it depends on lot of other things as well. like if you use KeepAlive widget, it won't dispose the widgets.